# How to put a variable into script scope?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've been using [Parametrized-pipelines](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines) in Jenkins and notice that while using parameters, the value is both useable from script scope as well as via params.variable.
PARAMETER == true
params.PARAMETER == true

In groovy, is it possible to add a variable to script scope from within a method? I would like to get similar functionality as the following...

```
// I don't want to have to declare value here
def function1(){
    value = 1
}
def function2(){
    assert value == 1
}
function1()
function2()
```

Is there a way to access value from within function2 without doing something like...

```
value = 0
def function1() {
    value = 1
...
```

Comment: No, this is not possible, since you're declaring a local variable. Maybe EnvInject is what you're looking for? Or other form of storing variable in process.

Comment: On further research, it doesn't look like there is a pure groovy way to do this. I went with setting everything using Jenkin's env, considering that my methods were ran outside of the node block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could also do somthing like :

```
def f1() { 
   env.aaa = "hello"
}

def f2() {
   assert aaa=="hello"
}

node{
  f1()
  f2()
}
```

Essentially setting it as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

this pipeline works fine:

```
def f1(){
    aaa = "hello"
}

def f2(){
    assert aaa=="hello"
}

node{
    f1()
    f2()
}
```

the pipeline definition as actually an instance of [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/index.html?org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.html) that extends [groovy.lang.Script](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html)

so groovy script properties should work here.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a particular reason why the node block has aaa in its scope? I had some code running outside of node, and that may have been why I wasn't able to use aaa. Do you know of some good sources on understanding how jenkin pipeline works?

Comment: it's connected to groovy. put in all, f1, f2, and node `println this.toString()` and you will see that in all cases you are inside the same instance of Script object. Script is a groovy object. and when you write `aaa="hello"` actually you call a function `setProperty("aaa", "hello")` if there is no variable `aaa` declared, `println aaa` corresponds to `println getProperty("aaa")`. http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope variable in script

```
 import groovy.transform.Field
 @Field List awe = [1, 2, 3]
 def awesum() { awe.sum() }
 assert awesum() == 6
```

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html